# How to compile a java file using the command line?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I want to test if Java is working fine on my machine, for that I wrote this part of code.

**this is the code :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("This is a Test class");
    }
}
```

The Test.java file is in the directory **C:\Users\HP\Desktop\JAVA Code**,

I execute this java compile command to compile the java class : **javac Test.java** , I got the error below :

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\JAVA Code>javac Test.java
Test.java:1: error: error while writing Test: Test.class (Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable)
public class Test {
       ^
1 error
```

Comment: do you have a package statement? is this a correct file "Test.java" ?

Comment: Try `dir Test.java` and check whether it exists.

Comment: Translation comment: *Le fichier spécifiér est introuvable* means *The specified file is not found*

Comment: @Stultuske I don't hava a package statement, it is a correct file, note that I tried to execute this code in eclipse, it works, but in command line, it does not work

Comment: @RobertKock I tried it, Test.java exists

Comment: Can you do `echo xx >Test.class` and `del Test.class` ? Any errors when you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your responses, finnaly I solved the error
This is the solution : I'm using **windows 10**, so when I compile the JAVA file, windows denied this process because of authorities, I added the **javac.exe** to the **authorized apps list in windows**, and it works.

[How to add apps to the authorized app on windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security)

Comment: You should click on the "tick" on the left to accept your own answer. It can be useful to anyone experiencing the same thing. I tried but couldn't reproduce the same error message, so it's good to know what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the blank space between JAVA and Code in your working directory. This sort of conventions (a directory name with blank spaces) might make ridiculous and time-consuming troubles. Please try  **C:\Users\HP\Desktop\JAVA%20Code**  as your path to Test.java file.

In case of using Mac, you could use **~/Desktop/JAVA\ Code**.

Hope it works out.

Comment: I changed the name of directory to javaCode, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you execute <cmd>java -version</cmd>  and <cmd>javac -version</cmd>  commands to ensure that your compiler version is set exactly as jdk version ?

Comment: I solved the problem, you can check the answer, thank you akarimin